# Unable to start firefox browser with jenkins user

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm unable to start firefox browser with jenkins user. I'm getting following error message on starting firefox from command line.

```
jenkins@quickrr-desktop:/usr/lib/firefox$ firefox
(process:22172): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion  'sys_page_size == 0' failed
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

Firefox version : 35.0.1
Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

no issue with jenkins . better you check with Ubuntu user forum. as i ee your DISPLAY is not set yet.. set it with proper value of :"Jenkins IP:Display value"

below link might be useful to you.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/486178/restoring-home-folder-firefox-launcher-problems-cannot-open-display

Comment: Above link doesn't help me.

Answer (score -1):

## linux ubuntu 14.04

command line

#### cp /usr home/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority

usr home is ur home directory's name

this is useful for me

that change X window system authority